# Create and use SMTP server on localhost

Tags: html-email

Im interested in starting an email marketing campaign and i need to know what happens if i create a SMTP server on LOCALHOST and send email from my computer without any limits.
Can this be done? Will the emails get to their target? Will they get in the INBOX ? Is it a good ideea or should i better use GOOGLE's SMTP Servers?

I need some advices from people with experience.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I hope you're not going to send spam.

Of course, you can install SMTP server on you local computer (there are a lot of available SMTP servers for different platforms), and it should work.

But, if you will send many emails, your ISP or recipient's SMTP servers can block you.

If you want to send a lot of email with marketing and advertisment, I think best and easy way to use 3-rd party service.

For example, we have expirience with http://www.unisender.com/en/. Each month we send our company newsletter to 100 000+ addresses of our customers.

Comment: I suppose this is where *DKIM* come in to place?